# How do I safely remove gwibber?

Tags: package-management, gwibber

I'm really in love with Ubuntu but I'm not used to Gwibber, for some reason.

I can't remove gwibber without removing the `ubuntu-desktop` package.

Is it safe to remove it, without ruining my desktop?

Comment: Today I tried to uninstall Gwibber. My computer worked for 15 minutes, and after refreshing the program's list, Gwibber still was among them. But after that my computer started to low-graphic mode and I cannot communicate with it. So I guess it isn't very safe to remove gWibber. I advise just not to use it, if you don't like it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, it is completely safe. The ubuntu-desktop package is just a metapackage, which means that it has nothing in it, just dependencies.
To remove, simply type this into a Terminal (Unity dash->Terminal) window:

```
sudo apt-get purge "gwibber.*"
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Don't worry, I can confirm that it won't harm the system. Uninstalling Gwibber is one of the first things I do and it does no harm whatsoever. ;)

Comment: Irfan Hanafi, if it works, could you mark it as the correct answer (the one that fixed your problem)?

Answer (score 2):

**To remove an account from Gwibber:**
Open Gwibber, click "Edit > Accounts" on the global menu (hover over the top of the screen where you see the title and the menu will show)
A window should pop up named "Online Accounts". Click on the site of the account then click "Remove account."

**To uninstall Gwibber (or any other piece of software):**
Open the "Ubuntu Software Center", search "Gwibber", click on the result, and click "Remove".

Answer (score 1):

I used the Software-Centre to remove Gwibber but the API thingy still launched my browser and asked for Facebook login details there. Not sure if it was related but it would be a coincidence if it wasn't because it never done it before.

After running:

```
sudo apt-get purge "gwibber.*"
```

My browser stopped launching by itself.