# How to uninstall Gwibber?

Tags: uninstall, gwibber, facebook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I safely remove gwibber?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66244/how-do-i-safely-remove-gwibber)

I am new to linux and I started using Gwibber but I wanna uninstall it from my Ubuntu.
What shall I do??
Quick help needed.
My facebook is always online right now.
I dont even know how to log out of facebook in Gwibber.
Please help..